# Remove dashboard links from wordpress

Tags: plugins, user-roles, author, capabilities

I am trying to remove two links from users dashboard keeping it on admin but it goes off on both user and admin.

One i need to remove from user dashboard and other is contact form plugin link contact.

I am trying t o use below code.also post link goes off.

```
      add_filter( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 99 );
  if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
      add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_menus' );
  }
  function remove_menus(){

      remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); //dashboard

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow the below code and also see the wordpress docs

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  //remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
  //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  //remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  //remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
  //remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
  //remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
  //remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
  //remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
  //remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  //remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

wordpress official docs :-

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

page restriction at admin site for particular user 
redirect when user reached there.

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'restrict_screen' );

 function restrict_screen() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {}
        else{
                $current_screen = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                $indexpage = 'index.php';
                $editpage = 'edit.php';
                $match = strpos( $current_screen, $editpage );
                $match2 = strpos( $current_screen, $indexpage );
               if( $match == TRUE || $match2 == TRUE ) {
                //  wp_die('get out');
                $current_admin = get_admin_url() . 'profile.php';
                header('Location: ' . $current_admin . '', true, 301);
                }
        }
 }
```

Comment: ok then how to add menu to subscriber dashboard ie edit.php

Comment: on which role do you want show dashboard. please enter list of role like admin,subscriber etc.

Comment: Want to add post to user dashboard using this `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){
if(!current_user_can('subscriber'))
    add_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //dashboard


}  as by default edit.php is not showing up...which enable users to post using their account

Comment: okay you want only subscriber can't access edit.php and other can access edit.php

Comment: subscribe can access edit page so as to they register and start posting from their registered account

Comment: then you should change role of subscriber to author or other role. its good think to do this.
if subscriber can edit and post data then what is the difference between other roles dude can you understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: my complete code is add_filter( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 99 );
function remove_menus(){
    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); //dashboard
remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
}

Comment: this gets remove from administrater even i choose as author

Comment: try this if(!current_user_can('activate_plugins'))

Comment: plugins......checked no

Comment: try your selft from https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: see my new edited answer

Comment: got it need to put all links in array adding end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}     solved

Comment: your welcome and please next do R & D on topic and go through the wordpress official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :)

```
add_filter( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 99 );
function remove_menus(){
    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
        remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); //dashboard
}
```

Comment: Thats works but my contact form 7 link displays and post page link disappears

Answer (score 0):

Admin menus and plugin menus are two different. You need to use separate actions to hide admin menus and plugin menus from admin dashboard. Here is how.

```
// Hide Admin Menus
function remove_menus() {

    remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );

// Hide plugin menus
function remove_plugin_menu_pages() {

    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' );
    remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
    remove_menu_page( 'itsec' );
    remove_menu_page( 'cptui_main_menu' );
    remove_menu_page( 'revslider' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_plugin_menu_pages' );
```

Comment: add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus1', 99 );
function remove_menus1(){
    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
        add_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //dashboard


}
trying to add this to user dashboard

Comment: Why don't you create a `editor` user role. I think you can avoid these `action hooks` and achieve what you want. As I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. This will only show Menu Items to Admin role & hide for other role(s). If you want to hide for Admin also, then remove the if statement.

```
// Hide Admin Menus from WP-Dashboard
add_filter( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
    function remove_menus(){
    if(!current_user_can('administrator')) {
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); //Contact Form7
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio_item' ); //CPT
      remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); //Contact Form7
      remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); //Tools    
      remove_menu_page( 'vc-welcome' ); //WPBakery Page Builder   
    }        
}
```